# Model completions and strong amalgamation property

Tags: logic, model-theory

The model companion $U$ of a theory $T$ in a language $L$ is a model completion if for every model $M$ of $T$, the union of $U$ and the diagram of $M$ is a complete theory in the language $L(M)$.  It is well known that a model companion is a model completion iff $T_\forall$, the set of universal consequences of $T$, has the amalgamation property (AP).

Can one go further and say that a theory $T$ has a model completion *only* if $T_\forall$ has the *strong* amalgamation property (SAP)?  (A theory has the SAP if the AP for $A_1 \hookleftarrow A_0 \hookrightarrow A_2$ may be witnessed in such a way that the intersection of the images of $A_1$ and $A_2$ is the image of $A_0$.)  Famous examples of theories having the AP but not the SAP, such as those of distributive lattices and fields of positive characteristics, do not exactly fit into this picture, I don't think.

Comment: Since SAP implies AP, a companionable universal theory with SAP has a model completion. Are you asking whether every universal theory with SAP is companionable?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I accidentally swapped the direction of the implication; please see my edit.   The question that I intended to ask was about consequences of a theory having a model completion.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense!

Comment: So to give a counterexample, you just need to find a universal theory which has a model companion, and which has AP but not SAP, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $T$ be the theory of algebraically closed fields. Then $T_\forall$ is the theory of integral domains. $T$ is the model completion of itself (and also of $T_\forall$), but $T_\forall$ does not have SAP.

For an even more elementary example, let $T$ be the universal theory of an equivalence relation $E$ such that every $E$-class has at most $2$ elements. Then $T$ does not have SAP (let $A_0 = \{a\}$, $A_1 = \{a,b\}$ with $a\neq b$ and $aEb$, and $A_2 = \{a,c\}$ with $a\neq c$ and $aEc$), but $T$ has a model completion: the theory of an equivalence relation $E$ with infinitely many classes, all of size $2$.

Comment: I changed the first example. The previous version was correct, but this version is simpler.

Comment: Thank you for the nice examples.  Do these counter example necessarily involve $T$ that are not universal?

Comment: @Pteromys Sorry, I'm not sure I understand the question. In both examples, we're looking at a universal theory and it's model companion. Model complete theories are  universal only in extremely trivial situations.

Comment: Actually, I don't remember what I had in mind back then.

Answer (score 2):

The (universal) theory of distributive lattices have a model completion, but it does not have the SAP.